# Why [Route] work for authorization in identity server 3

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, identityserver3

I am new to Open ID,Identity Server and Building an API, 
i have set up a Identity Server 3 and API and client, my server will give access token to client which it can be used when calling a API 
Startup in server is

```
public void Configuration (IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var options = new IdentityServerOptions
            {
                Factory = new IdentityServerServiceFactory()
                .UseInMemoryClients(Clients.Get())
                .UseInMemoryScopes(Scopes.Get())
                .UseInMemoryUsers(Users.Get()),

                RequireSsl = false
            };
            app.UseIdentityServer(options);

        }
```

and My API start up

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            //accept access token from indentityserver and require a scope of api1
            app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Authority = "http://localhost:62172/",
                ValidationMode = ValidationMode.ValidationEndpoint,
                RequiredScopes = new[] { "api1" }
            });
            //config web api 
            var config = new HttpConfiguration();
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            // require authentication for all controllers
            config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());

            app.UseWebApi(config);
        }
```

My Question is Why when i use

```
[Route("api/Search")]
```

it work like using [Authorize]

```
[Route("api/Search")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Companies(SearchRequest searchRequest)
{
}
```

why the blow code above work like :

```
[Authorize]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Companies(SearchRequest searchRequest)
        {}
```

---

More Information

in my controller this is method that i am calling and i am trying to force the user to be authorize

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Companies(SearchRequest searchRequest)
        {
            var caller = User as ClaimsPrincipal;

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
            Framework.BusinessLogicFactory factory = new Framework.BusinessLogicFactory();

            BusinessLogic.Search search = factory.CreateSearch();
}
```

But if i do not have [Authorize] or [Route("api/Sreach")] attribute on controller, any calls to API will get result back, 
and this is how i am testing my API

```
string APiURL = "http://localhost:59791/api/Search";
            var responses = GetClientToken();
            var clinet = new HttpClient();
            var value = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {

                { "CompanyNumber", " " },
                { "CompanyName", "test" },
                { "Address1", " " },
                { "Address2", " " },
                { "Address3", " " },
                { "PostCode", " " },
                { "CountryCode", " " },

            };
            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(value);
            var response = await clinet.PostAsync(APiURL, content);
            var t = response.StatusCode;
```

Comment: Can some one please tell me why my question got mark down ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have the `config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());` line in your API Startup.

This applies the `[Authorize]` to all of you controllers. So it isn't `[Route]` that is causing authorization to be applied but this filter.

Comment: So if it is because of config shouldn't it work with no [route] or [Authorize]?? but no authorization happen when there is no [route] or [authorize], and the authorization happened when there is [route] or [authorize]

Comment: If you remove all attributes from the controller, then the filter will still cause the controller to require authorization.

Comment: No, the authorization does not work when there is no attributes in controller, that is why i can not figure out what cause the authorization to work ?

Comment: In that case there's more to the story. You'd be better off adding to your question what you mean by "no authorization happen" (i.e. if you get data) and include some more code from your controller.